# The type 'MyApp' already contains a definition for 'MystatusBar'

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

MyApp.XAML

```
<StatusBar Name="MystatusBar" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" BorderBrush="Black"
                 Background="{StaticResource DarkBrush}">
                <StatusBarItem>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="m_StatusBarLineInfo"/>
                </StatusBarItem>
                <StatusBarItem>
                    <Separator/>
                </StatusBarItem>
                <StatusBarItem>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="m_StatusBarMessage"/>
                </StatusBarItem>
            </StatusBar>
```

MyApp.g.cs

```
     #line 722 "..\..\MyApp.xaml"
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
        internal System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.StatusBar MystatusBar;

 case 106:
            this.MystatusBar = ((System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.StatusBar)(target));
            return;
```

MyApp.xaml.cs

```
internal StatusBar MystatusBar;
case 110:
                    this.MystatusBar = (StatusBar)target;
                    break;
```

This is a usercontrol StatusBar . The error says "The type 'MyApp' already contains a definition for 'MystatusBar'"

The MyApp.g.cs file created automatically while building the project . I am stuck on this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you name a XAML element like you do with:

```
<StatusBar Name="MystatusBar" ... />
```

Visual studio will create a member for you with that name so that you can access it from code-behind. This is the instance you see in **MyApp.g.cs** which is a generated file. It gets created automatically when you change the XAML.

Therefore, when you attempt to declare another reference with the same name yourself in your code behind (**MyApp.xaml.cs**), you rightly get an error, since all three of these files compile into into the same class.

You do not need your manual declaration. You can just use the one that Visual Studio has already created for you.

Comment: Thanks removed the manual declaration from code behind . Its good now . Thank you

Comment: hey, 8 years later but I have the same issue with a decompiled .dll and this seems the solution but what does it mean that I don't need the manual declaration? what am I supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: @Axeltherabbit you do not need to declare your member in your code behind (`internal StatusBar MystatusBar;` in the OP's example). Visual Studio will have already declared anything you give a name in the xaml.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get an error that says anything like the following, it is usually correct:

> The type 'MyApp' already contains a definition for 'MystatusBar'

This usually means that there is already a member named `MyApp` declared in your `MystatusBar` class. It *may* be a different type of member, or even an `enum`, but you *will* have one declared there somewhere.

A good way to find it is to go to the error declaration (the duplicate member declaration) and comment it out. The error always occurs on the second declaration, or the one declared further down the page. So copy your duplicated member and paste it at the top of the file, just inside the class definition.

When you compile again, the error should now highlight the other member declaration, so you'll know where it is after that.

If that doesn't work and Visual Studio has got confused, just save your work and then close and reopen it. It should be ok after that.