# I decompiled a dotnet .dll with ILSpy but the xaml files have some issues

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, decompiler, ilspy

I decompiled a .dll with ILSpy and the code looks fine but I have a xaml file which is:

```
<Window x:Class="PrinterManager.ShellView" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrinterManager" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="Printer Manager" Height="450" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize" Icon="C:\Program Files (x86)\CENSURED" WindowState="Minimized" ShowInTaskbar="False" Visibility="Hidden">
.....MORE XAML STUFF....
      <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
....MORE XAML....
```

And I have a bunch of errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0102  The type 'ShellView' already contains a definition for '_contentLoaded' PrinterManager  C:\Users\PietroConvalle\Documents\DotNetDecompileThingy\source\PrinterManager\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows  C:\Users\PietroConvalle\Documents\DotNetDecompileThingy\source\PrinterManager\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows\shellview.g.cs   44  Active
Error   CS0111  Type 'ShellView' already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types    PrinterManager  C:\Users\PietroConvalle\Documents\DotNetDecompileThingy\source\PrinterManager\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows  C:\Users\PietroConvalle\Documents\DotNetDecompileThingy\source\PrinterManager\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows\shellview.g.cs   51  Active
Error   CS0111  Type 'ShellView' already defines a member called 'System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect' with the same parameter types  PrinterManager  C:\Users\PietroConvalle\Documents\DotNetDecompileThingy\source\PrinterManager\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows  C:\Users\PietroConvalle\Documents\DotNetDecompileThingy\source\PrinterManager\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows\shellview.g.cs   71  Active


And many more
```

But if I just remove `x:Class="PrinterManager.ShellView"` the errors are gone and it builds and runs fine.

I'm sure it's a trivial fix but I never coded in C#, I suspect that's some dependency or config issue?

Sorry can't share the full source for copyright reasons but happy to share a few extra bits if it helps.

Exported with latest ILSpy stable, c# 10.0 / VS 2022

UPDATE: this seems like my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/25849873/8340761 but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to change?

Comment: What's the question here? Sounds like you have a solution already, is that solution not adequate? If not, then you have a list of errors to work though. If you get stuck with one of those errors specifically someone might be able to help with that if you update the question to refer to a specific error.

Comment: Why does it error is my question? Shouldn't ILSpy decompile it just fine, how do I fix it? why is there ambiguity when I add the class in the xaml, I haven't solved the issue, I just got rid of the xaml for the moment to see if compiles fine without it, and does indeed

Comment: You've not provided the configuration or parameters given to ILSpy so no one is going to be able to tell you whether or not that's the issue.  It might be that the original developer has implemented a way to deliberately protect against this kind of reverse-engineering, or it could be a bug in ILSpy

Comment: no, no protection the code is just clear, seems more like a config or dependency version issue, just added the ILSpy export information

Comment: There are other tools that can do this, by the way, although asking about them would be considered off-topic on this site. Perhaps you could try [a different tool](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)?

Comment: nah, as I said the export looks alright, just need to figure out how fix this small issue, I also tried that and other tools, they just have worse results

Comment: An open source project like that uses GitHub to collect issue reports, https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/issues So don't bother SO.

Comment: I'm asking how to fix the C# project it might also be a problem with the decompiler but there is for sure a manual solution by editing the project, this seems a problem with the xaml file and should be an easy fix but I'm not familiar with C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it I just had to move each .xaml file next to the same file name .cs

This issue was actually fixed in ILSpy 8